# Improving regex in sed to replace values that matches string=value

Tags: sed

I need to replace a value that matches a string=value
so this is what I've came up with:

```
echo "some string=oldvalue" | sed 's/\(some string\=\)(.*)/\1newvalue/'
```

It works fine, I just wonder if there's a better, shorter way to accomplish the same

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `some_string` is a constant value, just use:

```
sed 's/some string=.*/some string=newvalue/'
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo "some string=oldvalue" | sed 's/some string=.*/some string=newvalue/'
some string=newvalue
```

But you may want to consider using a start marker so that you don't pick up other keys:

```
sed 's/^some string=.*/some string=newvalue/'
```

If you wanted to preserve the rest of the line (say, after a space), use:

```
pax> echo "string=old # comment" | sed 's/string=[^ ]*/string=newvalue/'
string=newvalue # comment
```

This works by limiting the item after the `=` to non-space characters.

Comment: Another problem I've just encountered which I forgot to mention
The replacement should take place for ONLY what's after the "="
so if the entire line is
some_string=oldvalue some_other_string=othervalue
I need it to replace only "oldvalue". Using .* will replace the whole remaining of the line after the "=" which is definitely not what I need...

Comment: @TuxSax, see the update, it's a matter of limiting the characters matched following the `=` character.

Answer (score 1):

If the value can't contain any `=`s, then it's shorter to do:

```
sed 's/=.*/=NEW VALUE/'
```